# Ansible pretty print json

Tags: json, ansible, pretty-print

when I'm running my playbook I get the debug output in the correct json format I would want it

```
"ansible_facts": {
    "routes": [
        {
            "subnet": "10.0.0.0/24"
        },
        {
            "subnet": "10.0.1.0/24"
        }
    ]
},
```

but when I export it to a file using the local_action directive it displays like this

```
[{"subnet": "10.0.0.0/24"}, {"subnet": "10.0.1.0/24"}
```

Is there any working pretty print module or in Ansible which would export my file in the same way as I see it in the debug messages?

Thanks!

Comment: `when I export it to a file ` => how do you do that ? Where is the task you use to achieve this ? There are several filter that might help you. The relevant one in your case should be `to_nide_json` => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply by export I mean the following

`local_action: copy content={{ routes }} dest=/etc/ansible/test9.json`. The file has the output in the format what you can see in my second output of OP but I would like to see it in a format what I get during the debug.

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator your to_nice_json trick has solved my problem!

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly the output you get on screen, but you could use a `template` task to print the variable, after passing it through a [`to_nice_json`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/to_nice_json_filter.html) filter. Example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_ansible_facts:
      routes:
      - subnet: 10.0.0.0/24
      - subnet: 10.0.1.0/24

  tasks:
  - template: src=nice_yaml_filter.j2 dest=/tmp/nice_yaml_filter.out
```

Please note that i am not using the same variable as you are, just a `my_ansible_facts` variable that i populated.

And the template file's contents, `nice_yaml_filter.j2`:

```
{{ my_ansible_facts | to_nice_json }}
```

Result:

```
[http_offline@greenhat-32 ANSIBLE_TESTS]$ cat /tmp/nice_yaml_filter.out 
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "subnet": "10.0.0.0/24"
        },
        {
            "subnet": "10.0.1.0/24"
        }
    ]
}[http_offline@greenhat-32 ANSIBLE_TESTS]$
```

cheers

Comment: Thank seems straightforward enough but it doesn't work.  The subnet facts are not hardcoded they are coming out from a previous module and I register them as routes "register: routes". I tried the following but my playbook doesn't want to run

`- name: display the data
    vars:
      my_ansible_facts:
        routes:
          - subnet: "{{ routes }}"

    tasks:
      - templates: src=/etc/ansible/nice_yaml_filter.j2 dest=/etc/ansible/test10.json`

Getting an error message of `ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>`